# Use dataframe column containing "column name strings", to return values from dataframe based on column name and index without using .apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df=pandas.DataFrame()
df['A'] = numpy.random.random(10)
df['B'] = numpy.random.random(10)
df['C'] = numpy.random.random(10)
df['Col_name'] = numpy.random.choice(['A','B','C'],size=10)
```

I want to obtain an output that uses 'Col_name' and the respective index of the dataframe row to lookup the value in the dataframe.
I can get the desired output this with .apply() follows:

```
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[ x['Col_name'] ], axis=1)
```

.apply() is slow over a large dataframe with it iterating row by row. Is there an obvious solution in pandas that is faster/vectorised?

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt` to flatten your dataframe and keep rows where `Col_name` equals to `variable` column:

```
df['output'] = df.melt('Col_name', ignore_index=False).query('Col_name == variable')['value']
print(df)

# Output
          A         B         C Col_name    output
0  0.202197  0.430735  0.093551        B  0.430735
1  0.344753  0.979453  0.999160        C  0.999160
2  0.500904  0.778715  0.074786        A  0.500904
3  0.050951  0.317732  0.363027        B  0.317732
4  0.722624  0.026065  0.424639        C  0.424639
5  0.578185  0.626698  0.376692        C  0.376692
6  0.540849  0.805722  0.528886        A  0.540849
7  0.918618  0.869893  0.825991        C  0.825991
8  0.688967  0.203809  0.734467        B  0.203809
9  0.811571  0.010081  0.372657        B  0.010081
```

Transformation after `melt`:

```
>>> df.melt('Col_name', ignore_index=False)
  Col_name variable     value
0        B        A  0.202197
1        C        A  0.344753
2        A        A  0.500904  # keep
3        B        A  0.050951
4        C        A  0.722624
5        C        A  0.578185
6        A        A  0.540849  # keep
7        C        A  0.918618
8        B        A  0.688967
9        B        A  0.811571
0        B        B  0.430735  # keep
1        C        B  0.979453
2        A        B  0.778715
3        B        B  0.317732  # keep
4        C        B  0.026065
5        C        B  0.626698
6        A        B  0.805722
7        C        B  0.869893
8        B        B  0.203809  # keep
9        B        B  0.010081  # keep
0        B        C  0.093551
1        C        C  0.999160  # keep
2        A        C  0.074786
3        B        C  0.363027
4        C        C  0.424639  # keep
5        C        C  0.376692  # keep
6        A        C  0.528886
7        C        C  0.825991  # keep
8        B        C  0.734467
9        B        C  0.372657
```

**Update**

Alternative with `set_index` and `stack` for @Rabinzel:

```
df['output'] = (
  df.set_index('Col_name', append=True).stack()
    .loc[lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1) == x.index.get_level_values(2)]
    .droplevel([1, 2])
)
print(df)

# Output
          A         B         C Col_name    output
0  0.209953  0.332294  0.812476        C  0.812476
1  0.284225  0.566939  0.087084        A  0.284225
2  0.815874  0.185154  0.155454        A  0.815874
3  0.017548  0.733474  0.766972        A  0.017548
4  0.494323  0.433719  0.979399        C  0.979399
5  0.875071  0.789891  0.319870        B  0.789891
6  0.475554  0.229837  0.338032        B  0.229837
7  0.123904  0.397463  0.288614        C  0.288614
8  0.288249  0.631578  0.393521        A  0.288249
9  0.107245  0.006969  0.367748        C  0.367748
```

Comment: I just tried to play around a bit with your solution. I wondered if it is possible to do the same with `df.stack()` since it also transforms the data wide_to_long. I can't do `df.stack('Col_name')` so I first `set_index('Col_name')` and then stacked the df but the data is differently sorted. For now I'm just curious about `df.melt('Col_name', ignore_index=False)`. My closest result was `df.set_index('Col_name').stack().reset_index().sort_values(by='level_1')` but still values in `'Col_name'` are sorted differently than in the original df. What would be the equivalent with stack?

Comment: Really appreciate it. Everytime you post something I learn more about pandas!.... BUT if I may say my (off-topic) issue was a little different. Given the df, part of your solution was `df.melt('Col_name', ignore_index=False)` . Just for this case (without the `'output'` column), how can I achieve this with the `stack` method. In my approach the 'variable' column is sorted right, but the 'Col_name' column gets totally mixed up (what I mean is, looking at your output it should repeat `[B C A B C C A C B B]` 3 times)

Comment: @Rabinzel. IIUC, use `unstack` instead of `stack` if you want to maintain order of `variable` column: `df.set_index('Col_name').unstack().rename('value').rename_axis(['variable', 'Col_name']).swaplevel().reset_index()`

Comment: @Mudjud. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Corralien. Yes, thank you its a huge speed up! Good explanation too, thanks!

Comment: @Mudjud just to satisfy my curiosity and maybe to let me learn something - could you compare speed of my answer with this .melt solution on your actual data and let me know if their speed is comparatable?

Comment: @SalamanderKrajza your solution is about 10% faster, but I am using dynamically assigned column names and its a bit easier to implement Corralien's solution at the moment. Im still playing around with both options. Either way, both solutions have a huge speed (6x) up over the ,apply() method

Comment: Thanks for testing that. I really appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pick each column name (or give list of possible names) and then apply it as mask to filter your dataframe then pick values from desired column and assign them to all rows matching the mask.  Then repeat this for another coulmn.

```
for column_name in df: #or: for column_name in ['A', 'B', 'C']
    df.loc[df['Col_name']==column_name, 'output'] = df[column_name]
```

Rows that will not match any mask will have NaN values.

PS. Accodring to my test with 10000000 random rows - method with .apply() takes 2min 24s to finish while my method takes only 4,3s.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = np.random.random(10)
df['B'] = np.random.random(10)
df['C'] = np.random.random(10)
df['Col_name'] = np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],size=10)
df["output"] = np.nan
```

Even though you do not like going row per row, I still routinely use loops to go through each row just to know where it breaks when it breaks. Here are two loops just to satisfy myself. The column is created ahead with na values becausethe loops needs it to be.

```
# each rows by index
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['output'][i] = df[df['Col_name'][i]][i]

# each rows but by column name
for col in list(df["Col_name"]):
    df.loc[:,'output'] = df.loc[:,col]
```

Here are some "non-loop" ways to do so.

```
df["output"] = df.lookup(df.index, df.Col_name)

df['output'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['output']), df[df['Col_name']], np.nan)
```